# openvpn list all active certificates

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

I have a openvpn setup on ubuntu that multiple users are connecting to. I want to list all the active certificates with their Common name. Is their a way of doing this ?

Comment: What certificates are 'active' for you? Ones that are used for ("currently") running tunnels or all possible certificates that can initiate tunnels? For the first - write a little connect script that saves all CNs (and remove them on disconnect) - for the latter: ask your PKI.

Comment: as an aside, i highly recommend using pfSense for new Openvpn server deployments, so you can take advantage of the awesome certificate management via web UI. pfSense has also come a long way in general, and makes some things that can take literally weeks to configure in PF doable in minutes. (load balanced outbound multiwan for instance).

Check out this talk if you are interested in pfSense: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckesvwkNiJE

Answer (score 10):

If you're using easy-rsa, check the `index.txt` file in the `keys` folder. It should contain a list of all the issued certificates and their subjects (including CN); valid certificates start with a `V` and revoked ones start with an `R`.
The current connections are listed in the status file (in my case, `openvpn-status.log` in the `openvpn` folder).

Comment: the index.txt file does not contain a list of issued certificates.  Perhaps you have it configured in a way that allows this; if so, please provide the config.

Comment: @lobi Well, I looked around and found some openssl-*.cnf files containing `database        = $dir/index.txt` in the `[ CA_default ]` section. I'm guessing that's where it is specified. It was like that by default, I didn't change anything except the "vars" file.

Comment: The `index.txt` file appears to contain a map of certificate (NN.pem) along with the SubjectName and a status of `V` for valid or `R` for revoked as well as the date it was revoked (valid have no date).

Comment: Where is this located??

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do that in this way:

```
# cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/
# cat index.txt | grep ^V | awk -F "/" '{print $7, $8}'
```

Lines in `index.txt` starts with `V` if the certificate is valid.

Result should looks like this:

```
CN=guest name=changeme
```

Comment: cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/
No such file or directory.

Comment: In my case, it was `/etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki`

Comment: mine is on /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/index.txt

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of current connections to the OpenVPN server either by using the status command over the management interface (see http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html), or by looking at the status file which is specified using the status line in the config files (see http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#server).

If you want to know who can connect to the OpenVPN server its a bit harder. OpenVPN will let anyone in whose certificate contains a signature generated with the CA key the server is configured to use. If you are using a third party PKI infrastructure they should have records of the certificates they have issued. If you are using the easy-rsa stuff then the certs should all be in that directory.